# Calling other smart contract onlyOwner question

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

can someone explain me why can't i call **Kill contract** from **Helper contract** if i set modifier and constructor to `owner == msg.sender` in **Kill contract** ? When i try to call from Helper its reverting and saying im not the owner even though i call from owner address. When i call directly from **Kill** contract with the same address it's perfectly fine.

Code below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Kill {

    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "You are not the owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor(address _owner) {
        owner = _owner;
    }
    
    function kill() external onlyOwner {
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function testCall() external pure returns (uint) {
        return 123;
    }

    function getBalance() public onlyOwner view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}

contract Helper {

    address public owner;

    mapping(address => Kill) public _counters;

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function kill() external {
        Kill(_counters[msg.sender]).kill();
    }

    function newCampaign() public {
    _counters[msg.sender] = new Kill(msg.sender);
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, in the context of the Kill contract, the msg.sender is the Helper contract.

The tx.orign is and always be your address, but in your case you are calling Helper, and Helper is calling Kill. So kill checks that the msg.sender (i.e. Helper's address) is the same as the owner's address (i.e. your address) and revert everytime since they are not the same addresses.

That's also why your call works when you call Kill directly.

Edit: After discussion in the comments with Kapitankot, the code looks like this

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Kill {

    address public owner;
    address public helper;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender || helper == msg.sender, "You are not the owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor(address _owner) {
        owner = _owner;
        helper = tx.origin;
    }
    
    function kill() external onlyOwner {
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function testCall() external pure returns (uint) {
        return 123;
    }

    function getBalance() public onlyOwner view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}

contract Helper {

    address public owner;

    mapping(address => Kill) public _counters;

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function kill() external {
        Kill(_counters[msg.sender]).kill();
    }

    function newCampaign() public {
        _counters[msg.sender] = new Kill(address(this));
    }
}
```

that way the helper contract and the owner can kill the Kill contract.
P.s. Do be careful of the fact that anybody can call the kill() function in helper contract

Comment: Olivier thank you for answer! So the only way is to set owner == tx.origin ?

Comment: Or set the owner as the address of helper. Glad I could help! If you could mark my answer as valid or upvote it that would be great!

Comment: Basically what i want to achieve is to make Helper contract to create new Kill contract and assign msg.sender to both. If you dont mind to check it, i have edited my code above. Thanks

Comment: Given your edit, since you are creating a new kill contract with the msg.sender argument, the owner of Kill will be the wallet address, so the owner check in Kill (i.e. msg.sender == owner) will still fail. You could use "address(this)" as argument in the newCampaign() function, like this: "_counters[msg.sender] = new Kill(address(this));" That way, you can kill Kill from Helper

Comment: Just checked: _counters[msg.sender] = new Kill(address(this));, and still when i try to call kill from Helper it says that Im not the owner .. do i need to change modifier ? Thanks

Comment: Or could you provide code ?

Comment: I just tried again on remix and using 'address(this)' in '_counters[msg.sender] = new Kill(address(this));' worked perfectly. Was able to destroy the kill contract by calling the kill() function in helper

Comment: Sure, but if You call directly from Kill contract its not working.. . What i want to achive is to call from Helper and be able to call with the same address directly from Kill contract too with the same address. Im out of home now, but i added some changes to modifier, will post it here when i come back. Do You have any other solution ?

Comment: Then you need to modify your kill constructor to save the wallet address and the helper address at creation time and change the kill onlyOwner modifier to be callable only by the owner or the helper address

Comment: Olivier could You provide a code please ? Thanks

Comment: Or at least constructor snippet

Comment: Added the finalized code in my answer! Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thank you Olivier! Just added to " accepted answer ". I have changed tx.origin to helper == msg.sender to avoid using tx.origin and it works perfectly and the modifier remains the same. Just in case anyone had a similar problem. Have a great day